# Embedding clang Compiler into OS X Cocoa App

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, libclang

As part of development for an application of mine that generates C source code, I need to be able to embed a compiler into my application so that it can generate executable object code. Since this is a sandboxed app intended for the Mac App Store, I cannot use `NSTask` to directly invoke `clang`, as the standalone tool apparently does not work under a sandbox. Pity.

I came across `libclang`, a library version of the compiler, which seems to do the trick. Using information from [here](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-01-24-introduction-to-libclang.html), I was able to grab a preconfigured `libclang` binary to integrate into my application. Trouble is, I can't seem to figure out what the `libclang` API calls are that process and generate an executable. I found this sample code:

```
string source = "app.c";
string target= "app";

llvm::sys::Path clangPath = llvm::sys::Program::FindProgramByName("clang");

// arguments
vector<const char *> args;
args.push_back(clangPath.c_str());
args.push_back(source.c_str());
args.push_back("-l");
args.push_back("curl");

clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter *DiagClient = new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::errs(), clang::DiagnosticOptions());
clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> DiagID(new clang::DiagnosticIDs());
clang::DiagnosticsEngine Diags(DiagID, DiagClient);

clang::driver::Driver TheDriver(args[0], llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple(), target, true, Diags);

clang::OwningPtr<clang::driver::Compilation> c(TheDriver.BuildCompilation(args));

int res = 0;
const clang::driver::Command *FailingCommand = 0;
if (c) res = TheDriver.ExecuteCompilation(*c, FailingCommand);
if (res < 0) TheDriver.generateCompilationDiagnostics(*c, FailingCommand);
```

Unfortunately, though, it won't compile. I get these errors:

[image: My errors]

Maybe I'm not including the right header files, I don't know. But given the lack off documentation for `libclang`, I would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Probably missing includes. `grep` your clang source tree for that missing type name and see what header it comes from.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I have, but including that one file gives nightmares with hundreds of others... oh, brother.